# For all sets A, B and C, if $A\setminus(B \cup C) = \emptyset$ ; then $A\setminus C\subseteq B$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For all sets A, B and C, if $A-(B \cup C) = \emptyset$ ; then $A-C\subseteq B$.
Is it true?
If it is, how to prove it?
I think it's true...

Comment: Remember, if $A\setminus B=\emptyset$, then $A\subseteq B$.

Comment: (From template of comments) After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Answer (score 2):

Notice that
$$U-V=U\cap V^c$$
and
$$(U\cup V)^c=U^c\cap V^c$$
hence we have
$$A-(B\cup C)=A\cap(B\cup C)^c=A\cap(B^c\cap C^c)=(A\cap C^c)\cap B^c=(A-C)\cap B^c=\emptyset$$
hence
$$A-C\subset B$$

Comment: we cant use this

Comment: What do you can use so?

Comment: definitions like x belongs A-C, then x is in A, not in C

Answer (score 1):

$A\setminus (B\cup C)=\emptyset\Rightarrow A\subseteq B\cup C\Rightarrow A\setminus C\subseteq B$. Done.

#### Another proof:

Because $A\setminus (B\cup C)=\emptyset$, we have that for all $x\in A$ it can't hold that $x\notin B\cup C$. So, for $x\in A$ we have $x\in B\cup C$ (by the way, this means that $A\subseteq B\cup C$). But if also $x\notin C$, meaning $x\in A\setminus C$, then $x\in (B\cup C)\setminus C= B$. So, $A\setminus C\subseteq B$.

Comment: the question should be like 
is "-" 
not "\"

Comment: @michael If you like it better that way, it's ok. I see you changed it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go for a purely logical proof then:

$x \in A \setminus C \implies x \in A $ and $x \not \in C ----(1)$

But  $A \setminus (B \cup C) = \emptyset \implies $ There is no $x$ such that $x \in A$ and $x \not \in (B \cup C)$

By $(1)$, $ x \in A \implies x \in  (B \cup C). $ But since $x \not \in C, \;  x \in B \implies  A \setminus C \subseteq B$